# Best way to create a copy of an object array with a new structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to know if there is a better option to create a copy of an object array with a new structure

Actually I do this (typescript):

```js
const carModels = (carList: Array<CarModel>): Array<SelectValues> => {
    const cars: Array<SelectValues> = []

    carList.forEach((car: CarModel) =>
      cars.push({
        value: `/api/modeles/${car.id}`,
        label: car.libelle,
      })
    )

    return cars
  }
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can help you with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typical use case for Array#map

```
const carModels = (carList: CarModel[]): SelectValues[] =>
  carList.map((car: CarModel) =>
  ({
    value: `/api/modeles/${car.id}`,
    label: car.libelle,
  }))
```

```js
const carList = [
 {id: 1, libelle: 1},
 {id: 2, libelle: 2}
]

const carModels = carList =>
  carList.map(car =>
  ({
    value: `/api/modeles/${car.id}`,
    label: car.libelle,
  }));

console.log(carModels(carList));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map(). But for such a simple task, I don't think there is a better way than the other options.

```js
const carList = [
 {id: 1, libelle: 1},
 {id: 2, libelle: 2}
]

const cars = carList.map(x => (
  {
    value: `/api/modeles/${x.id}`,
    label: x.libelle
  }
))

console.log(cars);
```

Comment: There's no need for the curly braces and return statement

Answer (score 1):

The `.map` function is exactly to be used in this situations. So you could do something like this...

```
const parseCarModel = (car: CarModel) => ({
    value: `/api/modeles/${car.id}`,
    label: car.libelle,
});

const cars: Array<SelectValues> = carList.map(parseCardModel);
```